# Storyboard shows dimmed views while working with svn

Tags: objective-c, svn, storyboard

I'm working in a small project with my team, and we share the same storyboard file. I'm encountering a problem regarding to the storyboard after updating it from the repository.

After updating the storyboard from my friend's commit, all of the view controllers are somehow blank (except for ones that are created by me). After some investigation, I found that the view controllers created by others all have their view dimmed like below:

[image: dimmed view]

When selecting the dimmed view, I see that there are some kind of options in the attribute inspector: 
[image: check]

by checking the "Installed" box, the view becomes visible again, but it also breaks some autolayout constraints applied to that view, and that is very inconvenient for us

Can anyone explain this, and show me a possible answer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my questions, just posting it here in case anyone will need it. 
Actually the problem has nothing to do with SVN, it's because I and my friends are using different size classes (a feature available from XCode 6.0) while modifying the storyboard (I use wAny|hAny, while another guy uses wC|hR), consequently he can see my views while I cannot see his.